# dynamically add text boxes using PHP

Tags: php, forms, textbox

I'm trying to make a form that the allows the user to add or remove inputs (text box) to a form if they click a "+" or "-" button.

Right now it will only let me add one box (and also remove it), but I can't add any more than that.

EDIT - I got it to work using GET. Here's what I did if you're interested.

```
<?
$j=1; //sets the value initially when the page is first loaded

if($_GET['num'] >= 1 ){
    $j = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['num'])+1;
}

//displays the text boxes
echo '<table>';
for($i = 0; $i<$j; $i++){
    echo '<tr><td><input type="textbox" name="input[]"></td></tr>';
}
    //displays the + and - buttons to add or remove text boxes
$a = $j-2;

echo '</table>';
echo '<a href="helplist.php?num='.$j++.' "> + </a>';
echo '<a href="helplist.php?num=' .$a. '"> - </a>';
?>
```

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem is. What is the value of $j?

Comment: I edited my code. Sorry about that.

Comment: on every submit, page load, j is 1 again. you have to store the state or use js fort this (much easier anyway)

Comment: When I echo $j it shows it as 2. Is there any way I can pass this value to another function which it reloads at the beginning? I don't know any js, I plan on learning it eventually. I'm currently working on a php project so I don't want to go out of my way at the moment.

Comment: now is a great time to start learning

Comment: so, is it not possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the value of $j in a hidden form field.

example: `<input type=hidden value=$j name=j>`

```
<?
if(!isset($_POST['j'])){
    static $j=1;
}
else{
 //j is a reference for $i in the loop. $i will loop while it is less than $j.

if(isset($_POST['plus'])){
    $j = $_POST['j']+1; //by incrementing $j, $i will loop one more time.
}

if(isset($_POST['minus'])){
    if($j < 1){ //if there is only one box the user can't remove it
        $j = $_POST['j']-1;
    }
}   
}
//displays the text boxes
echo '<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="j" value="' . $j . '">
<table>';
for($i = 0; $i<$j; $i++){
    echo '<tr><td><input type="textbox" name="input[]"></td></tr>';
    echo 'i='.$i.'<br/>'; //checking value of $i
    echo 'j='.$j.'<br/>'; //checking value of $j
}
    //displays the + and - buttons to add or remove text boxes
echo '<tr><input type ="submit" value="+" name="plus">
      <input type ="submit" value="-" name="minus"></tr></table></form>';   
?>
```

I didn't test this out, only to show you the idea behind it.

Comment: What about incrementing that or setting it to static?

Comment: Would this go in the loop or somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll give yours a try sometime. I ended up just passing the value through "GET" instead